# Apache php permission not working on mac osx

Tags: php, macos, apache, permissions

I want to have this easy script working but I keep getting the warning: 'Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in ...'
I have set the permissions right a thousand times (through the info screen in mac, I am not good with the terminal). I have set the permissions for the folder of my script to 777, I have set the whole user folder to 777, the /var folder, ... nothing does the warning disappear..

```
<?php
mkdir('/datatest');
?>
```

Comment: In your example, mkdir() will attempt to create the directory in / not /usr or /var or your webserver document root. Do you mean to create a directory such as /var/datatest? If so, that's the full path to use in mkdir().

Comment: I would like the script to create the folder 'datatest' in the root of the script. So if the script is test.php which exists in /sites/foo then I want the script to create /sites/foo/datatest

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarifying comment, if you want to create a directory in /sites/foo, then your code should be:

```
<?php
mkdir('/sites/foo/directoryname');
?>
```

Note this specifies the full path to the directory you want to create.  Make sure that you have permission to write to the parent directory (e.g. /sites/foo).

You may also try

```
<?php
mkdir('directoryname');
?>
```

Note no leading slash.  Same permissions comment applies.

Comment: Ok this works! Thanks a lot!
Could you also explain me why the script doesn't create the directory in the directory where the script is?

Comment: If the script is in the directory /sites/foo and you do not specify a full path in the mkdir() function, it should create a directory in /sites/foo if you have the proper permissions. If the script is in the directory /sites/foo and you DO specify a full path, then the directory will be created at that explicit location if you have the proper permissions.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add a . to the beginning of your file path to make it an absolute relative path... O_O

```
mkdir('./directoryname');
```

this will be relative to where the PHP script where the code resides is located.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Xammp directory, right click and select Read informations. At the bottom of it, click on the chains, enter your password and change permission to read and write to everyone. Now, click on the cog and choose Apply to included elements.

Refresh your page that includes the code, and tadam, mkdir will work.